# Centos 7: network.service failed to start because systemd starts the daemon too early

Tags: centos, networking, systemd

I have a kickstart server that installs Centos 7 without installing NetworkManager. Everything on it works fine, but the networking.

I'm able to get the networking working by logging in via tty1 and running

```
[root@centos~]# systemctl restart network
```

Which leads me to believe that it's starting too early.

When it first boots, checking the status of network via systemd shows:

```
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking


Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-10-04 07:46:02 PDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1525 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 04 07:45:55 centos.local systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Oct 04 07:45:56 centos.local network[1525]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Oct 04 07:45:56 centos.local network[1525]: Bringing up interface eno1:
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local network[1525]: Determining IP information for eno1... failed; no link present.  Check cable?
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local network[1525]: [FAILED]
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Oct 04 07:46:02 centos.local systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this specific question, so I'm asking here.

Thanks.

Config file below

```
#/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1

NAME="eno1"
DEVICE="eno1"
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
UUID="315e0366-a380-47f2-a9d4-4512a52cdaf2"
IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
TYPE=Ethernet
```

**EDIT:** Setting a static config in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1 seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: There is an issue with your ifcfg-eno1 file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

Comment: I've updated my post with the config file

Comment: And when you execute dmesg | grep "device en" do you see the network interface named eno1 or is it named something else?

Comment: I don't get anything from that. If I execute dmesg | grep "eno1" I can see that: `[    4.181832] systemd-udevd[466]: renamed network interface eth0 to eno1` Could this be the reason?

Comment: Try "ip link show" to see the system names for your interfaces. You may want to put "NM_CONTROLLED=no" in your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1 file, too.

Comment: eno1 is correct then, since it show eno(1-4). Adding `NM_CONTROLLED=no` didn't help.

Comment: Try commenting out the NETBOOT, IPV6INIT and UUID lines.

Comment: No such luck. I'm able to restart network.service and everything works after that. Just not at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered similar problems:

[image]

To modify the configuration files.(ifcfg-ensxxxx), as follows:

- Commented out "UUID=xxxx-xxxx"
- Add new option: NM_CONTROLLED=no    #"NM_CONTROLLED=no" indicates that this interface will be set up using this configuration file, instead of being managed by Network Manager service.

Reference:
[How to configure a static IP address on CentOS 7](http://ask.xmodulo.com/configure-static-ip-address-centos7.html)

Comment: Screenshots don't like very well on the first spot, I suggest to use copy-paste. Anyways, good answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a static configuration instead of DHCP seems to have resolved the issue.